# Custom toolbar not being set properly

Tags: android

In my 2nd activity default toolbar is being set somewhere and I'm not able to figure it out.

second_activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    ></include>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/user_posts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_below="@id/user_profile"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/black"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Preview of this layout :

[image]

The dark part is my custom layout.

main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        ></include>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Preview of main_activity.xml:

[image]

My custom toolbar is working fine in main activity.

Android.manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".NetworkCalls"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
</application>
```

I've defined theme to have no action bar at application level.

And the most weird part is when I run this on actual phone no toolbar appears in my 2nd activity and my custom toolbar takes up all the space on screen.

toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_nav_bar"
        android:elevation="4dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

**Edit: Removed the redundant part**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard_activity);

        setupDrawerList();
        setupDashboardListAdapter();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use the noactionbar theme in activities that you want custom toolbars for, post the activity java ]code

Comment: Did you post your complete .xml for the 2nd activity? I'm missing the declaration of the NavigationView, not sure if that may cause problems. And can you post how you initialize your ToolBar in your 2nd activity?

Comment: But I'm using noactionbar theme. I set that on application level and I even tried setting that on activity also but to no avail.

Comment: share your activity code

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau added complete xml code

Comment: Include your ToolBar in the LinearLayout under the DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawer layout should be set up similar to:

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <ToolBar/>
        <ListView/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView/>
</DrawerLayout>
```

Not sure if this fixes your problem, please post your activities `onCreateView()`

Comment: This did the trick.Thank you. But I still don't understand why preview showing up default toolbar

Answer (score -1):

It's because it is a title bar not an action bar and this is how you hide it:

```
//this line is to remove the title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//this line removes the notification bar (where the time is)
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

//you must set the content view after the above settings
this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_here);
```